# XPages Dynamic View Panel - show columns as links

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using a dynamic view panel along with a customizer bean (as demonstrated by Paul Calhoun on NotesIn9 back in episode 79 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQOGgVZpAcw).

The customizer bean is currently very simple, just to ensure the documents are opened in read mode :-

```
    public void afterCreateColumn(FacesContext context, int index,
        ColumnDef colDef, IControl column) {

        //Get a map of the session variables to read the view session scope variable
        Map svals = context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();

        //Create a variable for the current component
        UIComponent columnComponent = column.getComponent();

        //Create a reference to the column and set the links to open in read mode
        DynamicColumn dynamicColumn = (DynamicColumn) columnComponent;

        //To have every view open the selected documents in read mode add the following
        dynamicColumn.setOpenDocAsReadonly(true);

        super.afterCreateColumn(context, index, colDef, column);
    }
```

The dynamic view panel currently shows the first non-categorised column as a link to open the document. Can I add further customisation to show other columns as links, either instead of or as well as the first column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you should be able to do this in a couple ways. The way I've done it in my customizer bean before is to handle it when fetching the column information at the front, since the goal of [the bean](https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/XPages-Scaffolding/blob/9e4e70e88b1a447524f7edb785c4218fc1209aa6/frostillicus.framework/frostillicus.framework.plugin/src/main/java/frostillicus/xsp/DynamicViewCustomizer.java) is to match the view's design as closely as possible.

In your code there, though, you could also call `dynamicColumn.setDisplayAs("link")` or `dynamicColumn.setDisplayAs("text")` as appropriate to turn on or off link display.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. setDisplayAs(...) works well for what I need. Is there a set of javadocs that document the options available?

Comment: Sort of. There are Javadocs for the built-in controls (setDisplayAs comes from UIViewColumn) here: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/index.html?cm_mc_uid=60268102717314430069210&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1446558893 . I don't think there are official docs for the ExtLib classes, other than looking at the source.